# C# Script to login fails but manual works

Tags: c#, authentication

I'm working on a script in C# that needs to login to a website with a username and password that I've provided it. When I run the script, I can see that it DOES enter the correct user name and password but when the login button gets clicked by the script, the website says the username and/or password is incorrect. However, if I manually type in the same exact username and password, I'm able to login. What can be the cause of this? What am I missing here? Is there something I should be doing differently? Here is the code. I've got the user name and password stored in a global variable for use in this code.

```
driver.Url = "some-website.com";
driver.WaitUntilElementTextContains(By.XPath("/html/body/header/div/nav/div/form/a[1]"), "SIGN IN", 30);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='customerlogin']/a[1]")).Click();
driver.WaitUntilElementTextContains(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/main/form/div[1]/div[1]/label/span"), "username field", 30);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
//new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='userNameId_input']"))).Perform();
WebElement user = (WebElement)driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='userNameId_input']"));
new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(user).Perform();
new Actions(driver).DoubleClick(user).Perform();
//new Actions(driver).KeyDown(user,Keys.Shift).Perform();
new Actions(driver).SendKeys(Global_Var.userName).Perform(); 
//new Actions(driver).KeyUp(user, Keys.Shift).Perform();
new Actions(driver).DoubleClick(user).Perform();
//new Actions(driver).ContextClick().Perform(); 
//user.Click();
//.Clear();
//.iRobot(Global_Var.userName);
WebElement pass = (WebElement)driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='passwdId_input']"));
new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(pass).Perform();
new Actions(driver).DoubleClick(pass).Perform();
//new Actions(driver).KeyDown(pass, Keys.Shift).Perform();
new Actions(driver).SendKeys(Global_Var.passWord).Perform();
//new Actions(driver).KeyUp(pass, Keys.Shift).Perform();
new Actions(driver).DoubleClick(pass).Perform();
//new Actions(driver).ContextClick().Perform();
//pass.Click();
//pass.Clear();
//SharedCode.iRobot(Global_Var.passWord);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/main/form/input[6]")).Click();
```

Comment: Hard to tell without the actual values. There might be some special characters in your password that are not entered by `SendKeys` as expected. Have you verified the pw is entered correctly, maybe outputting it to a plain text field?

Comment: Yes it's been verified that it is sending correctly. The play where it says something about password is the variable name where the password is stored in.